# dart:io Process - How to run 'CMD start' on Windows?

Tags: flutter, dart

On Linux we are able to open url's using a simple io.Process call:

`io.Process.run("xdg-open", [ url, ])`

But trying to do the equivalent thing on windows

`io.Process.run("start", [url]);`

It fails with:
*The system cannot find the file specified.*

I'm guessing we need the path of cmd.exe, which is located at %ComSpec%. Tried doing a 'echo %ComSpec%, but getting the same error. Also tried hard-coding the path, but no success.

Here is our complete function:

```
ProcessResult result;
  try {
    if(Platform.isLinux){
      result = await io.Process.run("xdg-open", [ url, ]);
    }
    else if(Platform.isWindows){
      result = await io.Process.run("start", [url]);
    }
  } on ProcessException catch (e){
    Log.e(e?.message);
  };
  return result?.exitCode == 0;
```

[Edit] Updated title to be more accurate

Comment: What is your actual code that isn't working? You're giving pseudocode for your Windows call, which makes it impossible to say why it's not working.

Comment: It is the same code as Linux but using the "start" command, updated question to be more complete.

Comment: To call `start` on windows , you need to use this: Process.run('start', url, runInShell: true)`.
If all you want is launch a URL on all OSs, I wrote a lib for that: https://pub.dev/packages/open_url

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The title of your question doesn't match your code; that isn't trying to run `cmd.exe`, it's trying to run an executable called `start`. The reason it doesn't work is that `start` isn't an executable, it's a command built into `cmd.exe`'s interpreter. (Try running `where start` at a command prompt; compare with `where cmd`.)

If you want to run a `cmd.exe` command like `start`, you need to pass `runInShell: true` to `Process.run`. However, keep in mind that if you do you may need to be careful about special characters in your arguments.

(The answer to the question in your title is: `Process.run('cmd', [...]);`. But since what you want to do is run a command in the shell it's easier to use `runInShell: true` than to invoke `cmd` with `/c` and your command as a string.)

Answer (score 1):

Work example for Windows -

```
Future<io.ProcessResult> processRun() {
 var result = io.Process.run(
  'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\1cv8\\common\\1cestart.exe', [],
  runInShell: true);

   result.then((value) {
     print(value.exitCode);
   });
```

return result;
}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).